# Renaming Ruby on Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a way to rename the application in Rails 2?

Answer (score 27):

You can use https://github.com/morshedalam/rename to rename Rails 3 application

Comment: Worked with rails 4 as well.

Comment: Fantastic, it worked for me for Rails 4 also.  Very convenient gem.

Comment: Worked perfectly on Rails 4.2.7.1. I used command `rails g rename:app_to newname`. This renamed app top directory as well.

Answer (score 23):

Number of places in your files where your app must be renamed (Rails 3.1) or you will not be able to start your server. So do the following:

1) Rename the directory

2) Rename `module (yourapp)` in the Application.rb file.

3) Rename `(yourapp)::Application` in the following files:

environment.rb

routes.rb

config.ru

Rakefile

initializers/secret_token.rb

initializers/session_store.rb

environments/test.rb, production.rb and development.rb

4) You can also rename the databases in config.database.yml.sqlite3 to (yourapp)_development, (yourapp)_test etc. It may be necessary reload your databases in this case. I used the yaml_db gem and `rake db:reload` to do this and worked.

That should do it.

Answer (score 9):

I had some trouble renaming a Rails 3 app. 
I then found [this plugin](https://github.com/get/Rename) and it works like a charm.

Comment: +1! works awesome without any hassle. I am using Rails 3 though :P

Answer (score 8):

Rails 2 doesn't really have a concept of an application 'name'. The only thing that identifies your app is the name of the folder itself.

In Rails 3, it's a little different. Rails 3 projects are name-spaced to a module defined in `config/application.rb`. This application module is used to house your app, and you'll see it referenced by your `config.ru`, `config/routes.rb`, `config/environment.rb` and all the environments defined in `config/environments/`.

If you were to open a terminal session and run the command `rails new myapp`, your `config/application.rb` file would define the module `Myapp`, inside which will be defined an Application class, which extends Rails::Application. All the other files will reference `Myapp::Application`.

In both Rails 2 and 3, you will find a string key for your session defined in `config/initializers/session_store.rb`, which takes the default value of '_<myapp>_session'. It's not really tied to the "name" of your application, though you should try to keep it in sync to prevent any accidental session key name conflicts with other apps.

Answer (score 2):

just rename the application directory, nothing more. I did it several times, no issues.

Answer (score 1):

I've written the following script to do just that.  You can see it also at https://gist.github.com/danielpclark/8dfcdd7ac63149323bbc

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby
# Rename Rails Project (File: rename_rails)
# Copyright 6ft Dan(TM) / MIT License
# Check the config/application.rb for capital usage in project name by model OldProjectName
# Usage: rename_rails OldProjectName NewAwesomeName

# Replace string instances of project name   
`grep -lR #{ARGV[0]} | xargs sed -i 's/#{ARGV[0]}/#{ARGV[1]}/g'`
`grep -lR #{ARGV[0].downcase} | xargs sed -i 's/#{ARGV[0].downcase}/#{ARGV[1].downcase}/g'`

# Rename Rails directory if it exists
if File.directory?(ARGV[0])
    `mv #{ARGV[0]} #{ARGV[1]}`
    drc = ARGV[1]
elsif File.directory?(ARGV[0].downcase)
    `mv #{ARGV[0].downcase} #{ARGV[1]}`
    drc = ARGV[1]
end

# Delete temporary files (helps prevent errors)
drc ||= ''
if ['cache','pids','sessions','sockets'].all? {
        |direc| File.directory?(File.join(drc,'tmp', direc)) }
    FileUtils.rm_rf(File.join(drc,'tmp'))
end
```

And I've created a howto video on YouTube.  http://youtu.be/dDw2RmczcDA