# Renaming a Rails 4 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have created a Rails 4 app but the name has since changed.

I have updated the folder name, but I was wondering what files do I need to go into and update to have this new name throughout the site, or if there is rails command that will do this quickly and easily.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270373/renaming-ruby-on-rails-application (comment says it works for rails 4).

Comment: I'm not sure which answer your referring to. The rails plugin says it doesn't work for rails 4

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename rails 4 app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20988813/how-to-rename-rails-4-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/morshedalam/rename - I posted an issue there for you. It was great for me with rails 3.

survey says... it works great with Rails 4!!

Comment: Even worked in Rails 4.1.6! But you need to re-open the terminal without have being initiated server.

Answer (score 1):

You should search the directory for all instances of the app name:

`ack "app-name"` and figure out what each one is doing. You will often times have named spaced modules under the old name.

`config.ru` and `config/application.rb` for sure should be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Add `gem 'rename'` to Gemfile then do  `bundle install` .
After bundle install
 `rails g rename:app_to name_of_app`
 And if you are using mongoid then you need to rename the database name in `config/mongoid.yml`