# Is it okay to name every project "app" in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I don't like the idea of hardcoding brand names in my projects. I get the feeling they might change later, and sometimes I don't even have a name yet. So, can I do `rails new app` for my every project and just rename the directory? What problems could arise from that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3270373/renaming-ruby-on-rails-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could result in some issues

the name of the application has some implications on the internals and using several apps named "app" might have undesired effects and bugs.

for instance, sessions and cookies are named after the app name, so they will all be the same

further more, this have effects on outside sources such as AWS buckets, github repos, and even folder names - it will be pretty hard to figure out what all those /app folders are.

so if the only app you have and are working on is called app - it shouldn't be a problem (besides the name app, which is really lame, and if you are working on it at least call it by greek letters or something..)

if you are going to work on more that one app.. do yourself, your coworkers, your file-system, github, and everything else - name your app.

Also an important side note - how can you have an app and not know what it is about?

and if the name is not suiting anymore.. change it  https://github.com/morshedalam/rename

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I never said I wouldn't give the app a name (and obviously the directory). I just didn't want to hardcode it in a bunch of ruby files.

Comment: Besides that, the part about sessions and cookies was actually helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you rename your project, you must rename it in some files too. (routes.rb, environment.rb, application.rb, ...)

Answer (score 0):

[Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps), for example, let you rename your app any time with `apps:rename`.